# Графики matplotlib в цикле

Tags: python, matplotlib, графики

Как мне доработать мой код, что бы графики строились в предопределенных областях ax_1,ax_2,ax_3,ax_4?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

ax_1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax_2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax_3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
ax_4 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4)

ax_1.set(title = 'ax_1', xticks=[], yticks=[])
ax_2.set(title = 'ax_2', xticks=[], yticks=[])
ax_3.set(title = 'ax_3', xticks=[], yticks=[])
ax_4.set(title = 'ax_4', xticks=[], yticks=[])

x=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x[i],y[i])
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
x=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
y=[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]

for i in range(1,5):
  ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, i)
  ax.set(title='ax_'+str(i), xticks=[], yticks=[])
  ax.plot(x[i-1],y[i-1])

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]